# Git not moving un-staged changes to another branch

Tags: git, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I am in the master branch (accidentally), and I make some changes to files, I used to be able to checkout to a new branch and the unstaged changes could then be committed to the correct branch.

This is working partially but after I commit the changes on the correct branch, I checkout to master again and it says something like: `cannot create file [filename] permission denied`.

Then I have to commit the same unstaged changes on master. I have never had a problem with this before.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL2 and Git version 2.17.1.

Is this a setting that needs to be changed ?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Given that your problem is "something like" that, perhaps the answer is something like this one: https://superuser.com/questions/1352207/windows-wsl-ubuntu-sees-wrong-permissions-on-files-in-mounted-disk

Comment: Thank you for that info. I now see that the problem is when I open a directory in VS code via `code .` (from WSL), and then add or create files and directories, `root` is automatically the owner of the file/directory. Is there a way to change this behavior? When I create the file/directory from the WSL command line, the ownership is set properly. So it seems like a VSCode issue?

Comment: I don't have Windows so I don't know the answer to that, but it seems likely to be searchable: https://www.google.com/search?q=wsl+files+creation+owned+by+root

Answer (score 1):

After investigating I realized, thanks to torek, that it is not a Git or VSCode issue. It is a WSL issue where creating files directly in the vscode interface results in those files being owned by the root user in the WSL distro.